# Warning C4018 with int and UINT32, but not with int and UCHAR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, warnings

Using VS 2017, this fragment generates the compiler warning C4018:

```
UINT32 numChars(2);
int i;
for( i=0; i<numChars; i++ )
```

but this doesn't:

```
UCHAR numChars(2);
int i;
for( i=0; i<numChars; i++ )
```

Recall that

```
typedef unsigned int UINT32
typedef unsigned char UCHAR
```

Why the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing integers of different types, the usual arithmetic conversions apply. This means that both integers are first promoted if applicable and then, if the results are still different types, the type with less precision is converted to the one with more or, if both have the same precision, the signed one is converted to the unsigned one.

So in your first case you have an unsigned int and a signed int. Neither one is promoted because they're both already ints, so the signed int is converted to unsigned. This triggers the warning when it happens as part of a comparison.

In your second case, the `UCHAR` is promoted to a signed int because it can be represented by one. Now you're comparing two signed ints, so no further conversion needs to take place.